# Jasmine test for BehaviouralSubject inside componet is not getting covered

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am planning to write test cases for the Angular project using jasmine tests. Below is the code that I am trying to cover.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {

  availableData: BehaviorSubject<string[]> | undefined;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    let emptyArray: string[] = [];
    this.availableData = new BehaviorSubject(emptyArray);
  }

  getData(name: string) {
    return this.http.post(serviceURL, { "name": name })
  }
}


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './service/my.service';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'My Application';
  selectedEnv: string = "";
 
  constructor(private service: MyService) {
  }
  
  updateData(name: string) {
    this.dbservice.getData(name).subscribe(
      data => {
        let resp: string[] = Object.values(data);
        this.service.availableData?.next(resp);
      });
  }
}
```

In the above AppComponent class for updateData method, I am trying to cover **this.service.availableData?.next(resp)** where **?.** is not getting covered in any way.

My configuration is of strict policy which is not allowing me to remove *`| undefined`* at `availableData: BehaviorSubject<string[]> | undefined;` in MyService

Can someone please help me how to cover **?.** this for Behavioural Subject.

***Note: I can't change any configurations and declarations as well***

Answer (score 0):

If this is your code, then `availableData` is never undefined. Wouldn't it be better to just initialize your service like this? Also the `emptyArray` is a weird thing you have there.

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
  readonly availableData = new BehaviorSubject<string[]>([]);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData(name: string) {
    return this.http.post(serviceURL, { name })
  }
}
```

Besides that, it feels very counter-intuitive to update the subject from within the component. And sounds like you are trying to solve an issue which should be solved differently.

<sub>Maybe a copy paste error, but there is a `availableDbs` and `availableData` in your code</sub>